# Problems with very simple tutorial in Cuda by Example

Tags: c, cuda

I'm studying Cuda C on the "Cuda by Example" book. At chapter 4 there's a very simple tutorial about how to sum 2 vectors. 
I basically copied the tutorial:

```
`#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #define N 5

 __global__ void Add(int *a, int*b, int *c){
 int i = blockIdx.x; 
 if(i<N){
 c[i] = a[i] + b[i];   
 }
}

 int main(){
 int a[N] = {1,2,3,4,5}, b[N] = {5,6,7,8,9}; 
 int c[N];
 int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c; 


 cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, N*sizeof(int));
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, N*sizeof(int));
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, N*sizeof(int));


 cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
 cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 Add<<<2,1>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c); // HERE IS THE CRITICAL LINE !!!!!!


 cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


 int i; printf("c[i] = ");
 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf("%d ", c[i]);
 }


 cudaFree(dev_a); 
 cudaFree(dev_b); 
 cudaFree(dev_c);

 printf("\n");
 return 0;
 }`
```

So according to the book, the parameter N in the line `Add<<<N,1>>>` is the one who tells the device to split the operations (contained in the Add function) into N blocks; the index `i` defined in each block assumes a value that goes from 0 to N so that just a single operation is run by each block simultaneously (parallel computing).

Here's the problem: if i type a random number (1 or 2 or 3 or 0 and so on) instead of N  (for example `Add<<<2,1>>>`), the program keeps giving me the sum of all the elements of the vector while it should stop to the first or second or third accordingly to the number i typed instead of N... Why do i keep getting the same result all the time? should the number of elements vary depending on the number of blocks i desire?

hopefully i made myself clear and if you don't understand let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to initialize `dev_c` to a known state, e.g. to all zeros. If you ran your kernel with N threads at some point, the global memory can still contain the previous results, and the same physical region can be allocated as `dev_c` over and over again.

For example, add the following lines:

```
...
int c[N] = {0,0,0,0,0};
...
cudaMemcpy(dev_c, c, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
...
```

One more thing to try is to add `printf` to the kernel, and observe the output.

Comment: mmm... none of your tips solved the problem... i understand the fact that i should initialize the vector but the second line is not correct since it's correct my way for sure... either way the problem still ramains

Comment: I meant, add initialization of c[N] with zeros, and add `cudaMemcpy` from `c` to `dev_c` after your two `cudaMemcpy`s to initialize `dev_c` in the device global memory. Also updated the answer with trying `printf`.

Comment: you were right!!! the cudaMemcpyHostToDevice tricked me!!! Thanks so much!!! i wasted 3 hours for this ahah